# Open terminal in a specific folder

Tags: java, terminal, runtime, processbuilder

```
String command= "/usr/bin/xterm"; 
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();  
Process pr = rt.exec(command);
```

Using the code above I managed to open terminal using java, but the "problem" is that the terminal opens in the folder where my java project is located. How can I open the terminal AND redirect it automatically to a specific folder e.g I want that the terminal gets opened in the Download folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing it is to pass your working directory as a `File` to the `Runtime`'s [`exec` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-java.io.File-) with the following signature:

```
exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir)
// Executes the specified string command in a separate process with the 
// specified environment and working directory.
```

Something like this:

```
String command = "/usr/bin/xterm"; 
File workDir = new File("/home/Download");
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec(command, null, workDir);
```

Comment: it works. thanks. Is it possible to call a script directly when opening the terminal. I dont want to call the script directly. I want to open the terminal and after the terminal was openen I want to call for e.g ./mySHScriptInsideDownloadFolder.sh

Comment: In this case you should use `-e` option:
`String command= "/usr/bin/xterm -e 'script.sh; bash'";`

Comment: unfourtunally it does not work. "Failed to execute child process “'myTestShell.sh;” (No such file or directory)". same error as before

Comment: any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Try: `String command= "xterm -hold -e sh mySHScriptInsideDownloadFolder.sh";`
Is this what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `xterm` with `-e` option to change directory when it starts. As in:

`String command= "/usr/bin/xterm -e 'cd /home; bash'";`

Comment: I get the error: There was an error creating the child process for this terminal. Failed to execute child process “'cd” (No such file or directory)

Comment: I edited my answer. You also need `bash` so that the terminal doesn't exit after command passed by `-e`.

Comment: no unfourtinally it didn't work. I changed the "xterm" to gnom and wrote this: String command= "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper -e 'cd /home/maljursa; bash'"; it does not work